# How to make a base converter from base 10 to base 9 and then to base 7

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a base converter, from any base between 2 and 10. That code should make two conversion, for example: I want to convert 100 in base 9 and the result shall be conversed in base 7 the output should look like this 121 - for first conversion and 202 for second conversion.
However my code doesn't solve correct the second conversion, most likely because it sees 121 still in base 10 and not 9 and I don't know how to solve that.

```
void converter(int originalNumber, int b1, int b2)
{
    int arr[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (originalNumber != 0)
    {
        int divide = originalNumber / b1;
        int remainder = originalNumber % b1;
        arr[i] = remainder;
        originalNumber = originalNumber / b1;
        i++;
    }
    int counter = i;
    std::reverse(arr, arr + originalNumber);//I'm reversing the order of elements in array so it can show properly

    int numberInB1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        numberInB1 = numberInB1 * 10 + arr[i];
    std::cout << numberInB1 << std::endl;


    i = 0;
    while (numberInB1 != 0)
    {
        int divide = numberInB1 / b2;
        int remainder = numberInB1 % b2;
        arr[i] = remainder;
        numberInB1 = numberInB1 / b2;
        i++;
    }

    counter = i;
    std::reverse(arr, arr + counter);
    int B1inB2 = 0;// here i will store the numberinB1 in the second base(b2)

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        B1inB2 = B1inB2 * b1 + arr[i];

    std::cout << B1inB2 << std::endl;
}
```

Example: 40 in base 10 will be converted in base 5 that is 130. now I will convert 130 in base 5 to base 4 and that is 220

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why compute `int divide = numberInB1 / b2;` if you aren't going to use `divide`?

Comment: I recommend constructing a [mre]. If making the MRE doesn't end a few divide and conquer passes into construction with you finding and fixing the bug, add the MRE.

Comment: Sorry for that, i missed it

Comment: why do you want to do two conversions at once? You can remove the second half of the function and call it once with 7 and once with 9. Doing it both at once has no apparent advantage, rather that seems the be the problem

Comment: Tactical note: You're a lot better off with a function that does the conversion and then returns the result. Let the caller print the result, do another computation based on it, or whatever. You get a much simpler, easier to reuse, and easier to debug function. In general it's best to work in little building blocks than big functions. The rule of thumb is "Do one thing and do it well."

Comment: on the other hand for converting a number given in some base (not 10) to another base, you would still do one conversion at a time. Try to change the first half of the fucntion to not use hardcoded base 10 but with parameter `originalbase = 10;`. Then you would still need only the first half of the function.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i can do it twice but my purpose was to make 2 in same function however i made a secoind function wchich contains just on conversion and i tried to call it twice and i got the same issue

Comment: `std::reverse(arr, arr + originalNumber);` makes no sense.  At that point `originalNumber` is zero (the very reason the prior `while` loop terminated), making that reversal invoke a no-op (zero length sequence). That should be `std::reverse(arr, arr + i);`

Comment: @WhozCraig that isn't the issue here, the result is the same

Comment: Glad one of us has clearly identified the issue here. Doesn't change the fact that that reverse call is nonsense. It will always do *nothing* because you're passing a zero-length sequence.

Comment: Write two functions: one to convert from a decimal to base N, and one to convert from base N to decimal. This will be both less error prone and more useful in the long run

Comment: @TimRandall This is likely to be a school homework where he is required to do things in a certain way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestions:

1. Don't `std::reverse` your array - you can simply iterate through it backwards.
2. Integer values are binary; don't stuff your `base 9` or `base 7` values into it - it makes no sense. You need to print it out? Print the elements of your array.
3. Don't repeat the same code twice, use another function. If you need to keep an interface (function signature) - just call that helper function from there.
4. You can fix your problem by saving the `originalNumber` and reuse it for the second half. This won't be needed if you use the helper function.

Something like this (this won't work if `originalNumber` is `0`):

```
#include <iostream>

void printInBase(int value, int base) {
    int arr[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        arr[i++] = value % base;
        value /= base;
    }
    while (i--)
        std::cout << arr[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void converter(int originalNumber, int b1, int b2)
{
    printInBase(originalNumber, b1);
    printInBase(originalNumber, b2);
}


int main() {
    converter(100, 9, 7);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful!